# Check type without importing the type from external library

Tags: python

I want to write a decorator which runs some code depending on the type of data that gets passed in. Problem is, I'm writing this for a library and I don't want to have to add Pandas to the dependencies just for this one thing.

```
def my_function(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):       
         if isinstance(my_input, pd.DataFrame):
             # ...CODE TO RUN
    return wrapped
```

One thing I considered is to have a pickled version of a DataFrame packaged with the library. This seems to work:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.to_pickle(pd.DataFrame, "df_type.pickle")
>>> DataFrame = pd.read_pickle("df_type.pickle")
>>> isinstance(pd.DataFrame(), DataFrame)
True
```

Is there a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If panda is not installed on the user's environment, then you won't get a panda dataframe as input, so you don't have to worry about it. So you can just test if panda is installed and only add this code path when necessary:

```
try:
    from panda import DataFrame
    has_panda = True
except ImportError:
    DataFrame = None
    has_panda = False


def my_function(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):       
         if has_panda and isinstance(my_input, DataFrame):
             # ...CODE TO RUN
    return wrapped
```